# If $g(x)=2f(x/2)+f(2-x)$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all lying in $(0,2)$ how to find the interval where $g(x)$ increases?

Tags: functions, derivatives

If $$g(x)=2f(x/2)+f(2-x)$$ and $\hspace{.1cm} f''(x)<0$ for all lying in $(0,2)$ how to find the interval where $g(x)$ increases?

I differentiated it once and twice but I'm not being able to draw a conclusion. Hints please!

$g$ and $f$ are real valued.

Comment: what did you found as second derivative?

Comment: g'(x)=f'(x/2)-f'(2-x)   then    g''(x)=f''(x/2)/2+f''(2-x)

Answer (score 6):

We know that $g(x)$ is increasing on intervals where $g'(x) > 0$.

You correctly applied the chain rule to get $g'(x) = f'(\tfrac{x}{2})-f'(2-x)$.

So you need to determine for what values of $x$ is $f'(\tfrac{x}{2}) > f'(2-x)$ true?

Since $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0,2)$, $f'(x)$ is decreasing. Thus, $f'(a) > f'(b)$ iff $a < b$.

Now, can you figure out when $f'(\tfrac{x}{2}) > f'(2-x)$?